# How are they equal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to understand one of the steps in a solution.
It is given, $1 + \frac{1}{2} + .....+ \frac{1}{2^n} $$= 1+ \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{5} +.....+ \frac{1}{8}) +...+ (\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1} +...+\frac{1}{2^n})$

Intuitively thinking, the sum on RHS should be greater than the sum on LHS but I'm not sure. How do we arrive at this step?

Edit:

[image: When <span class=]$u_{r_n} = u_{2^n}$, why would they take $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5} +..... \frac{1}{2^n}$ when it should be $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3} +…...\frac{1}{2^n}$" />

Comment: That's obviously false. I suggest you post the full solutions so we can better understand the context of your problem.

Comment: $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{2^n}$ might just mean $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{5} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{2^n}$ (aka $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^{n}}\frac{1}{k}$), which would clearly equal $1+ \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{5} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{8}\right) +\cdots+ \left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1} +\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Maybe you're right, but that's definitely not what the heading suggests

Comment: @MinusOne could be right. I think I interpreted it wrong. I have changed the title

Comment: @Learner There is a very profound concept, which all mathematicians seem to have learned in their crib and forgot how _not to_ understand it, hence you'll almost never encounter it in the books. See, $n$ in the expression $u_n$ and $n$ in the expression $u_{2^n}$ are _totally different,_ unrelated things.

Comment: How are they different? Since $u_{r_n}$ is a subsequence of $u_n$, it has to be same. Right? @Ivan Neretin

Comment: A subsequence is not the same as the sequence, otherwise we wouldn't be needing a word for it. $u_n$ is one term, $u_{r_n}$ is another. Now to the point: does your question still stand?

Comment: Yes, my last comment wasn't clear I was answering to your _" $n$ in the expression $u_n$ and $n$ in the expression $u_{2^n}$ are totally different, unrelated "_. I don't think they are different. How are they? Also, I know that a subsequence is a subset of a sequence. That's not my doubt. My doubt is how they have expressed $u_{2^n}$ (In the picture that I have attached in my question above). I don't understand the two steps after _Now $u_{r_n}$ = $u_{2^n}$_ @Ivan

Comment: The first step is to write down all terms, one by one. If we were to write $u_8$, we would expand it as $1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18$. Is that clear? The second step is to put brackets around them in a certain manner.

Comment: My question is, how is $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5} +..... \frac{1}{2^n}$ = $u_{2^n}$?

Comment: I firmly believe this is best explained by example. What is $2^3$, for example? Is it not 8? So $u_{2^3}$ is just $u_8$. Now what is $u_8$? Is it not what I wrote before?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you so much! @Ivan